# How to reference a cell in a msgBox when another box has a certain value in excel (VBA).

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to get a corresponding cell to be entered into a msgBox when a cell in that row hits a certain value. For instance, if C1 > 3.45, I want a message box saying "The value at " + Range("A1") + " is too high." This would extend for the entirety of the array.

I have been attempting to modify the simple script.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Target = Me.Range("C1:C100")
    If Target.Value > 3.45 Then
        MsgBox "The Value at "+ Range("A1:A100") + " exceeded limit."
    End If
End Sub
```

I know I am missing something, but I can't figure out how to correlate the numbers, and have them return. I know that I could with a Match and utilizing the general form of

```
 Set targetRange = [range]
 targetRange.FormulaArray = "=[insert array formula]"
```

But I can't seem to get them to work correctly.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: It appears to me that what you want to do is loop through all of the cells within a range and pop up a `msgbox` if one of those numbers exceeds a threshold?

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: If it would continue through the cells once if found a threshold, that would be preferred as well. I wouldn't want it to stop if it found one.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something like

```
for i = 1 to 100
  if cells(i, 3) > 3.45 then
    msgbox "Cell C" & i & " is too high. The corresponding time stamp is " & cells(i, 1) & "."
  end if
next i
```

This will alert the user each time a cell in that range was "too high".

Comment: I will try that, but could you explain something so I have a deeper understanding rather than just copy/paste. 

When you utilize the cells(i ,3), does this automatically cycle through? Essentially using i as a placekeeper? 

(apologize if this is a stupid question, I have not been working with VBA a terribly long time)

Comment: It will 'cycle' through cells C1 through C100. C is the 3rd column, hence the 3. i refers to the row numbers 1 through 100. Not a stupid question at all. Keep learning!

Comment: Also, is it much more complicated to reference a separate cell? The reason I don't really want to reference cells specifically is that the cell is categorized by a date/time, which is in column A, and the data itself is in column C. Being able to see the timestamp initially gets rid of more searching.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your last comment.

Comment: I want the box that pops up to be able to reference a timestamp located in the A column but do the analyses on the C column. So If C3 is over, It would return the timestamp A3 in the message box.

Comment: Very well then. I edited my solution somewhat to address this.

Answer (score 0):

Single liner without loops (for fun - touch harder to understand!)

```
MsgBox Join(Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF(ISNUMBER(C1:C100),IF(C1:C100>3.45,""C""& ROW(C1:C100),""x""),""x"")")), "x", False), ",")
```